# Strange behaviour when appying a ColorMatrix to an image in .Net, WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gdi+, colormatrix

The method below, takes a colour matrix and applies it to the supplied image. There are a couple of things to note:

(1) It is not a function
(2) The same image is used to create the graphics object, and as the source of the DrawImage method.

```
Public Sub ApplyMatrixToImage(ByVal matrix As ColorMatrix, ByVal image As Image)
    Using atts As New ImageAttributes
        atts.SetColorMatrix(matrix)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)
            Dim width As Integer = image.Width
            Dim height As Integer = image.Height
            Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, width, height)
            g.DrawImage(image, rect, 0, 0, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, atts)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I don't know if it's bad practice not to create another bitmap to render the final image into, but the strange thing is the method works fine for a colour balance adjustment (Matrix30, 31 and 32), but does nothing for an opacity adjustment (Matrix33).

What's going on?

Comment: @nobugz: Could you please elaborate on that - I'm doing exactly this in an app that I have in production - and I haven't noticed any problem. Are you saying that I'm in for a nasty surprise in the future?

Comment: I've seen it mishave when you draw a Bitmap onto itself.  I forget the exact details, should however be enough to add a few lines of code.

Comment: @nobugz: Thanks for the warning. Maybe the problems appears if you try to rescale it at the same time? Then I can easily imagine weird things happen. [When working with LARGE bitmaps (hundreds of Mb) it is nice if those extra lines of code can be ommitted, since out of memory exceptions easily occurs, since a bitmap requires all of its memory to be contigous...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* I understand your question correctly: you are asking why you cannot alter the alpha channel with this method? (Why it should be a function instead of a sub elludes me completely.)

But why it doesn't work as you may expect with opactiy/transparency I understand perfectly. :-)

The .DrawImage method (combined with the ImageAttributes) will DRAW each altered pixel onto itself (since the width and height are the same). Note that it will *draw* - not *replace*. This means that the original pixel value will *blend* with the newly calculated pixel value. Among other things, this means that if the original pixel if completely opaque, there is no way that that will change. Painting with a partially transpararent color over something opaque will still yieald an opaque color.

Comment: Ah, thanks that explains it. Thanks also to nobugz for the warning.